# How can i copy an object passed from another class, to another class?

Tags: java

I have an object in a constructor that needs to be passed to another class. I am using threads, and i need to share a certain variable to all of the threads.

I need to take the BankExample object in the constructor, and copy it so i can pass it to in withdraw method call (in the transaction class) in the run method.

The passing looks a little something like this.

Main class----->runnable class----> action class.

```
 public class WithdrawThread implements Runnable {
    //I take in a thread numer so i can tell which threads run in the terminal. 
   transaction withdraw = new transaction();
    int threadNum;
    int balance = 0;
    public WithdrawThread(int num, BankExample bal){
        threadNum = num;

    }

    public void run(){
        //calls the withdraw method in transaction because i have a single method that takes care of  reducing the balance amount. 

        withdraw.withdraw(threadNum, balance );
    }
}
```

Comment: You can copy an object with `.clone()`. http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/cloning/a-guide-to-object-cloning-in-java/

Comment: If I clone an object, will the clone update the original?

Comment: There is no single answer here. Please read up on deep clone vs shallow clone, since that will make a difference to this behavior.

Comment: It will be best if you start following the naming conventions (CamelCase class names) and other standards from the start...
Objects/instances of classes are best made immutable, this approach avoids any problems in multithreaded setup and eliminates the need in cloning too...

Answer (score 0):

`WithdrawThread(...)` is pretty much the way you might want to do it. Just create another method more relevant.